# MySQL procedure wit cursor not running properly

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor

I have prosedure which suposed to update some info . in table , but . its  doing . some this compliterly wrong  and not . updating . my . table

```
CREATE DEFINER=`andrey.`@`ip` PROCEDURE `sp_visits`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE cursor_VAL VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE min_date DATETIME DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE max_visits INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT hash_id FROM .ANDREY;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO  cursor_VAL;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

   select @max_visits := max(visits)
    from ANDREY where hash_id = cursor_VAL ;

    select @min_date :=min(date(transaction_ts)) 
    from ANDREY where hash_id = cursor_VAL and visits =@max_visits;

   update ANDREYt 
   set visits = @max_visits+1
   where hash_id = cursor_VAL  and date(transaction_ts) between date(@min_date) and DATE(@min_date) + INTERVAL 7 DAY;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END
```

when I run it from workbench it instead of running it return me some records # @min_date :=min(date(transaction_ts))
2018-07-20

I dont understad why because I didn't specify return for this procedure, also dont understand why its not updating my table, when i am running statements manually not in procedure logic is working, but  doesn't in procedure. Any Ideas?

[with this cursor i am trying to resolve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511255/select-with-window-function-dense-rank-in-sparksql)

Comment: Using `SELECT` in the procedure will return the rows that it selected.

Comment: Don't forget that there is a difference between `@max_visits`/`max_visits` and `@min_date`/`min_date`, see [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) and [13.6.4 Variables in Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-variables.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do things like:

```
select @max_visits := max(visits)
from ANDREY where hash_id = cursor_VAL ;
```

in the procedure, the result of this query is returned as the result of the procedure. You can solve it by using `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT MAX(visits) INTO @max_visits
FROM ANDREY where hash_id = cursor_VAL ;

SELECT MIN(DATE(transaction_ts) INTO @min_date
FROM ANDREY where hash_id = cursor_VAL AND visits = @max_visits;
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know this difference between SQL server and Mysql :) learn something new today :)